# NAnt <script> The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System'

Tags: .net-4.0, nant

We use NAnt to build our .NET 4.0 solution. One of our .build scripts has inline C# within a  block. This is working fine on all machines except my own which is new. I have Visual Studio 2010 with the .NET 4.0 Client Profile and the Extended Framework installed. Earlier .NET versions are not installed.

When executing the script compilation fails with The namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace name 'System'. I have checked the NAnt.exe.config and the following framework element IS being used:

```
 <framework 
          name="net-4.0"
          family="net"
          version="4.0"
          description="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 Release"
          runtimeengine=""
          sdkdirectory="${path::combine(sdkInstallRoot, 'bin')}"
          frameworkdirectory="${path::combine(installRoot, 'v4.0.30319')}"
          frameworkassemblydirectory="${path::combine(installRoot, 'v4.0.30319')}"
          clrversion="4.0.30319"
                >
```

This matches correctly the version of the framework I have installed. My question is, how can NAnt be not finding System.Linq given that it must be using .NET 4.0? The NAnt version is 0.85.

Any help here appreciated.
Michael

Comment: The error inexplicably went away. It would be good to have this question deleted.